# Is it possible to change the build no. after archive an iOS project?

Tags: ios, testflight

The version of the iOS app I submitted to iTunes Connect for Testflight beta testing is almost expired. AFAIK in order to extend the 30-days trial period I need to submit it again but with an incremented build version. Since the code base I archived is long time ago and I do not want to revert the code base to that version and archive it again. I just wonder if there is any possible way to change the build number of an archived iOS project. I would like to submit version 1.3.6 (1.3.6.8, which is already in iTunes Connect for beta testing) again as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Why is it a problem to get back to that state of the code? You're using a version control tool, right?

Comment: Actually no problem at all, just being lazy. Yes, I am using git.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you still have the original archive then of course. An Xcode Archive is just a directory, with a specific hierarchy.

You should just

1. Open the Xcode Organizer - the one on the screenshot in your question
2. Right click on the version you want to modify
3. Select "Show in Finder"
4. Right click on the archive "file" (something like: "ProjectName 9-8-15, 7.34 AM.xcarchive")
5. Choose "Show Package Contents"

You should use a search tool to scan through the folders to find the version number in every file. For a basic iOS app it's enough to modify two files: `Info.plist` and `dSYMs/YourProjectName.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist`.

You're done at this point, but the organizer does not pick up the changes. You can just duplicate the whole `.xcarchive` file/folder and change the date with like one minute. Re-open the Organizer and you'll have your new version there.

Actually, you should probably just leave the original `.xcarchive` as it is and start with duplicating it before opening with "Show Package Contents".

Comment: You also need to edit the version number in `Products/Applications/YourProjectName.app/Info.plist`

Comment: Worth noting that the key you are looking for in the .plist files is 'CFBundleVersion' for the top-level info.plist and the dSYMs/ version, and then is 'Bundle Version' in the Products/ plist that William Grand alludes to above.  In order to get to these, remember to right click -> show package contents rather than try to navigate downwards (or just use terminal)

Comment: The amount of times I've done an archive, realised I forgot to bump the number, groaned and then re-archived is comically high. However, this method doesn't really make it any faster! I'll probably just stick to re-archiving

Comment: I'm surprised no1 made a script for this yet

Comment: where is the applications folder? @WilliamGrand

Comment: The Applications folder is under`/Users/{your username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/{your archive date}/{xcarchive file}/Products/Applications`

Comment: What @DanWebster said.  This is the kind of thing that drives Devs crazy the world over, and Apple could fix in less than a single hour.  It's astouding to me that this problem has persisted for so long.  I think Apple needs to actually spend some time with Devs, and maybe look over their shoulder and just answer questions until they are blue in the face.  Pay me well enough to do it, and I'll happily do it.  It would certainly make devs a lot happier and a LOT more productive, which is beneficial to Apple.

Comment: Also, the above method is difficult to execute.  Tried it, and two files came back in the search, and no idea how to edit them to change the number.