# Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store > Icon in PNG format

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

when I try to submit the app

> Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store
>   Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or
>   via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta
>   App Review

---

I'm providing **App Store Icon** with 1024px*1024px PNG format in iTunes Connect but still getting this error

Comment: if you are using xcode 9. New icon is added which needs to be updated in xcode. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406686/xcode9-warning-items-90704-error-itms-90022

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release/46348976#46348976

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In Xcode, they have added one additional app icon size with 1024px * 1024px[image]

Go to `Assets.xcassets` and you can find this new addition at the bottom of your app icon image set.

Once you add app icon with 1024pt, it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 38):

As stated here we need to add one more icon, called 1024x1024px App Store Icon. Create a png icon of resolution 1024x1024.

Go to Project General Setting Tab

[image]

Click on No. 4 which opens the app icon sets. The following section will be visible.

[image]

Scroll down and you will see the App Store iOS icon set.

[image]

Preferably add the icon inside "AppIcon.appiconset" folder.

[image]

you can locate the folder by clicking the folder icon next to "Identity and Type" on the right side of your icon selection screen.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: PS: If png format didn't work, use the image as jpg. For me, it was jpg that worked. Cheers!!!

Comment: Strangely, I did this, and it passed the build, and sent it to itunes connect. When it is "ready to submit" on testflight, I add a group and hit submit, and I get this error AGAIN!?

Comment: I went through the illustrated steps and it worked, but i did show the icon already existed in the location.

Comment: Also, I found that despite telling me that my binaries were rejected (or whatever the missing icon error message was), they were all waiting for me in iTunes connect - to attach to my app submission, so I'm unsure if those were actual errors or warnings.

Comment: @JohnTyner, I'm not sure. For me, the icon was missing (means there was no 1024px resolution icon in the folder) in the location. So I manually saved an icon to that folder and selected it as the "1x App Store iOS 1024pt" icon. And my errors went away. This is so strange, different people are getting different issues. Don't know why. My app was a hybrid one. What is your's, native or hybrid?

Comment: @2xSamurai - Cordova (ionic) hybrid

Comment: @JohnTyner, Hey I'm also using ionic. Ionic 1.3.2. Which version are you using? Maybe I can help. Also please post the error message you are getting. You are able to get it to build successfully and also make an archive and upload it to iTunes connect right.

Comment: Mine was already there.  phuckin' rotten Apple.  messes up my versioning ALL the time…now that this version is on the store, i can't use it but nor can you delete it.  Forcing me to compile it again with a newer version number.  You would think the richest company in the world would have better products.  Developing for iPhone sux!

Comment: Is there any way to add this to an existing archive? Or do I have to re-archive and re-upload?

Comment: @Andrew I archive it again after making the changes. You can modify the archive I guess. Try this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447866/is-it-possible-to-change-the-build-no-after-archive-an-ios-project

Answer (score 10):

You need to include additional icon of **1024x1024pt** size in **Assets.xcassets**.

Please find the below steps.

1) Go to **Assets.xcassets**.
2) Drag and drop the icon of 1024*1024pt in **App Store iOS 1024pt** field of Assets.xcassets.

For more information please find the below GIF representation.

[image: Demonstarte of adding the icon in the xcassets]

Hope it works!!!

Answer (score 4):

I'll quote just what Claude31 said here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90543

> May be useless question, but have you check the exact size of png image (in finder information) ?

In my case, the client sent an image to me called xxxx1024x1024.png, and the real size was 4000 x 4000. So, if you didn't create the image, is worth checking it.

Answer (score 3):

You can open this image in preview and select file -> Export... and set format png and check  alpha . and save image and use updated image. i hope issue will be resolve.

Answer (score 2):

```
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon.png</string>
            <string>icon@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon-72.png</string>
            <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

you need the App Store Image of your app in 1024 x 1024px without round corners and properties, see this answer Code Sign Error Xcode

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem my by chance. After doing tests with different types of .pn file "with transparency" and "without transparency" in neither of the two chaos worked for me. The problem was in the name that I put the collection in the App-Icon, the name had a "tilde" accent. I removed the accent and apple validated the compilation.

Comment: It seems this is a comment but you are using the "answer" section for that, which is wrong. It seems some other folks here have done the same. Please use comments sections for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 12 you can have a Swift UI app that gives you this error ONLY for the MacOS version but NOT for the iOS version when you submit for review.

The trick is to add the Mac App icon images and sizes to the Images.xcassets folder as well as TAG that folder in the Attributes panel with 'Mac OS'.  For some reason that's turned off.

Doing that will allow your Mac OS app to be ACCEPTED for 'review'.

Hope that helps someone.  I've almost spent two days chasing this one down.

Comment: I'm in a rush trying to upload my Catalyst app, got this error when trying to submit for review, and your just saved me, thanks for sharing!

Comment: The same happens when trying to submit a Mac Catalyst App to the App Store. Thanks for sharing, this saved me hours.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was the Sketch app was exporting incorrect images with the size 1024x1025.

Answer (score 1):

Per the message you get from XCode you can also do this from App Store Connect after the fact.

[image: App Store Connect Operation Warning]

My Apps > Prepare for Submission > App Store Icon > Select image.
[image: App Store Connect - select image]
Has to be 1024x1024px png with no alpha channels or transparencies.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/).

2xSamurai's answer is a preferred longer term solution to avoid repeatedly doing this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to not use 'â' in the App Icon group name.

Answer (score 0):

1-)Xcode 9.4.1 open and open a new project.

2-)Create new assets catalog.

3-)fill in the required icons correctly.

4-)This AppIcon catalog right click and show in finder,open AppIcon.appiconset folder and copy all things in folder.

5-)Open old project,old project AppIcon catalog right click and show in finder and open folder delete all things.

6-)Paste in the folder you copied.

7-)Clean, Build Project and Archive.

And Succesfully Upload App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the an image 1024 X 1024 and rename it to "icon-1024.png" on the `app/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/` and add the json below to `app/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json`

```
    {
          "size" : "1024x1024",
          "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
          "filename" : "icon-1024.png",
          "scale" : "1x"
    }
```

For me is work

Answer (score 0):

My issue actually came from the Development Assets. My Assets folder directory was in this spot and caused the issue because on build it was ignoring this folder. AppName -> General -> (Target Column) AppName -> Development Assets. Make sure your files are not in there like mine was!

Xcode Screenshot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I had a hybrid iOS/macOS project, that started off as an iOS project.
I had a lot of icons in my AppIcon image set, including a 1024 one.
I checked if it was shared among all targets, and it was.

In the end, I sent my 1024 to https://www.appicon.co, and checked iPhone/iPad and macOS, and got many more icons than before, including a 1x and a 2x AppStore icon.

This time, it went through without any issues.

A giveaway is, that when you select a build in the AppStoreConnect, and your latest build is showing a generic icon, something is wrong.