# App stopped working after publishing to app store in adhoc for testing

Tags: ios, xcode

My published app stopped working after xcode upgrade. My Xcode version is now 9.0.1. Publishing goes well except an error in the last stop of upload "Missing app store icon. ios apps must include a 1024x1024px app store icon in png format."
 but the app quits without throwing any errors on the device. The interesting thing is that it works ok when I attach the device to my mac and runs the application. Doesn't show any errors. Please let me know how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Chances are it has nothing to do with an icon. Check the device sys logs or sync with iTunes and see if there are any jetsam or crashes for the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987694/missing-app-store-icon-ios-apps-must-include-a-1024x1024px-app-store-icon-in

Comment: ho in your assets and in appicon there will be a missing icon of 1024 X 1024. Just add it.

Answer (score 0):

its simple just add an icon of size 1024x1024 to your app icons folder or xcassets file whatever way you have chosen for your icons

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to publish the app correctly. It was a mistake in renaming the app. I created a new cordova project with the new name and copied the existing code to the www directory. Now everything works ok.