# Unable to add an iOS build for review on the iTunes account as it gives an error just when you add it for review

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build, ipa

I have an old project in objective C, we have been keeping it updated for the past few years. And it works perfectly even today as well.
But for creating a build i.e IPA , we have been using a script that automatically copies the code from repository and takes the input like bundle identifier, certificate name , app icon and other inputs and creates an IPA file which I upload to the appstore through Transporter.

The script was locally set on a Mac intel machine and used to work perfectly till the machine crashed.

Now on a new M2 machine, and  Xcode 14 and 15 ,  the script is still able to create the IPA and it is successfully uploaded on the TEST FLIGHT, but as soon as I add it for Review, it gives the following error :

***A 1024 x 1024 pixel app icon for your app must be added to the asset catalog in Xcode.***

The only thing that has changed is new machine which has M2 processor and the MacOS .

The last successful build that was made from the old machine was made using Xcode 14 and on MacOS Montery.

I have already tried various options I found in on the  stack overflow and apple site but nothing is working.

I am pasting here the block of code from the script which creates the IPA.

Here is the [SCRIPT](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/O87HzxCy#link)

Interesting thing is if I create the build of this same code from XCODE itself and export the IPA it works perfectly fine and adds to review without any error, but IPA from this script gives an error when I try to add it to review.

I already checked that it has the 1024 by 1024 icon inside the icon asset.

Comment: Please check this reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987694/missing-app-store-icon-ios-apps-must-include-a-1024x1024px-app-store-icon-in

Comment: @Chetu - I already checked this and then posted the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I was able to fix the error. The error says - Missing 1024by1024 icon but this was not the issue. In the newer Xcode and MacOS, in the *SUPPORTED DESTINATION* section, there is a new option which is automatically added by the Xcode itself - ***Mac(Designed for iPAD)***.

[image]

I just removed that option, created the build , uploaded to the appstore and Apple accepted it.

The error from apple is completely misleading. I already had the 1024 by 1024 icon and even I already tried putting all the icons for iOS as well as for Mac even though my app was not designed for Macs, still it kept giving the same error.

But as soon as I removed the Mac option from the supported destination, the error from Apple store disappeared.